# Android Studio, events for a lock screen

Tags: android, android-studio, svm, lockscreen

I want to write user authorization/identification base of a app for android, using android studio and most likely SVM or some other classifier. 
The problem is I'm not really familiar with android studio and need some help with starting things up.

Are there any specific events I should use for a reasonable amount of data I can later provide for my classifier to learn?
It most likely will be a few lock screens to put in pin, some gesture and so on. The provided data shall be classified by a classifier to help with identification of a user.

I haven't been able to find much on this topic anywhere, and yes I will dig into documentation, however maybe someone already have some nice idea how to go about it.